# How to connect to Docker bridge network from host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For a test project, I want to have the following network connectivity

```
                           +---------------------------+
                           | redis-service-1 in docker |
                           +-----------+ B +-----------+
                                       | R |
+--------+                             | I |
|  Host  |    --->                     | D |
+--------+                             | G |
                                       | E |
                           +-----------+   +-----------+
                           | redis-service-2 in docker |
                           +---------------------------+
```

What I want to achieve is for my app running on `Host` it should be able to connect to both of the Redis services running in two docker containers using the DNS routing given by docker.

`docker-compose.yml` looks like the following:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  redis-service-1:
    image: redis:5.0
    networks:
      - overlay
  redis-service-2:
    image: redis:5.0
    networks:
      - overlay
```

Ideally after `docker-compose up` on the host I want to be able to ping both of the containers as following:

```
> redis-cli -h redis-service-1 ping

> redis-cli -h redis-service-2 ping
```

But I am unable to connect to these containers and Redis inside them from the host machine.